# Why yarn should update library?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

When i try to update one package in my project (Redux-form from 3 to 6), yarn updating react library too. Why? How i can debug this part?

I was trying: 
Delete old version of redux form and add new version with this command
Yarn install redux-form

Answer (score 0):

`redux-form` 6 has three `peerDependency`

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.3.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.0"
 }
```

So in order to work, it need these three. If you don't have one, probably `yarn` is forcing you to upgrade.